# Remove lines with specific pattern at the beginning of them

Tags: php, text

I have a text file of approximately 25,000 lines. About 525kb.

Some lines have random text at the beginning.
Some have long strings of semicolons.

Some others only have three semi-colons and then a space and optionally more text on the same line. These are the lines I want to remove.

Here is a sample....

```
   ;;; Updated Time 20120706122706
   ;;; Generic DEveloper Output

   ;;; Some Random Comments
   ;;; I got some more...
   ;;; Yet another uneeded line
   ;;; Thanks for using StackOverflow <http://stackoverflow.com>, or...
   ;;; Not.

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Banana Production

   [Data_Release_Version]
   Version=12586
   Released=20120706122706

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Baseline Properties

   [BaseLineProperties]
   Comment=BaselineProperties
```

----- and so on.

Once it gets to the first line with 4 or more ; on the line, I need the rest of the file as there are no ";;; " lines.

Trying to find something fast instead of reading everything line and writing it back out if it doesn't match ";;; ".

File is ASCII (possibly UTF-8) text type file.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time, assistance and knowledge.

Comment: Can you try explaining what you want again. It's not very clear. Do you want to remove lines that have more than 4 semicolons?

Comment: I want to remove lines that start with ";;; " and not lines that have more or less than 3 semi-colons then a space.  As soon as I hit a line with 4 or more semi-colons in a row, I can stop removing lines.
I basically want to remove a header that has a random number of lines at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

What I would suggest is to use `file_get_contents()` and save file's contents in a variable as a string, then use `explode()` that string at every newline character, then in a `foreach` loop, use `preg_match()` to check if the line begins with 3 semicolons and a space, if it dosent, put it in another array named `$output`. After foreach, `implode()` `$output` and add a newline character and use `file_put_contents()` to print it in another file. Hope this helps :-)

code:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents($filename);
$array = explode("\n",$string);
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if(!(preg_match("^;;;\s",$arr))) {
        $output[] = $arr;
    }
}

$out = implode("\n",$output);
file_put_contents($path,$out);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends.. I would try to load into a string, then do a explode() with newline, so it's in array, then run a foreach with a skip on any that doesnt have strpos == 0 -AND- strpos !== false, you can put in a continue to skip to the next line if it doesnt match.

Another option, is to parse, and skip, or even using fseek, and such. Depends on alot of different factors to determine whats going to be fastest.

You can implode later on, and add the newlines back in, and then push out a file, and/or use line breaks. Depending where the output is supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave the answer yourself:

Make a script that reads the input file line by line in a loop (while). It writes every line into an output file if two conditions are met: 1. a flag ("done") is FALSE and 2. the line does NOT start with ";;; " (not the blank). This removes those lines starting with three semicolons. Once you come about a line containing more semicolons you set the flag to TRUE, thus the remaining lines wil be copied without being examined.